# Unable to update a value with Flask and jquery/json

Tags: jquery, python, flask

Colleagues,

I am designing a web page to show a gauge and need to update every second. I am using flask and jquery. I am not sure why, but is not updating the value (ent_direc)on the page.

On flask I have :

```
@app.route('/update',methods=['GET'])
def retorno():
    get_value()
    return jsonify(ent_direc=ent_direc)
```

and on my page index.html i have

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="background-color:#ffffff"></canvas>
<script>
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
 var radius = canvas.height / 2;
 var ent_direc={{ent_direc}};
 ctx.translate(radius, radius);

 drawClock();

 setInterval(function(){update_values()}, 1000);

function drawClock()
{
    drawFace();
    drawNumbers();
    drawTime();
    drawMajorticks();
    drawMinorticks();
}

function update_values()
{

         $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
            $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT+"/update",ent_direc,
                function(data) {
                    drawClock();

                });
}
```

My question is when I execute update_values, and receive the updated value of ent_direc, can I call directly the global function drawClock()? I mean, I am jumping in the middle of the code, with out instiate ctx or canvas .

Any idea what might be wrong? for sure , the problem is on the client side, since if I go to /update, I do get my variable displayed on the page.

BTW, also see the get messages, so the client asks for the variable, it gets it from server, but is not updating my page.

192.168.1.7 - - [12/Sep/2015 01:10:51] "GET /update HTTP/1.1" 200 -
192.168.1.7 - - [12/Sep/2015 01:10:52] "GET /update HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Comment: There is quite a bit of code missing making it hard to see exactly where the problem is going. Could you create a jsfiddle with a [mvc](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?